# Mapping JSON to ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, json, class, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I have our staff in a json file, and had the idea to use that data with ES6 classes. The more I work with this, the more I feel as though I may be missing something. I had this working in coffeescript as such:

```
fetch  = require('node-fetch')
domain = 'domain.com'
apiSrc = 'api.domain.com'
slug   = 'people'

class Person
  constructor: (json) -> {name: @name, title: @title, school: @school, bio: @bio} = json
  email: (username) ->
    username.replace(/\s/, '.').toLowerCase() + '@' + domain
  profile: ->
    content = []
    if this.name   then content.push("#{@name}")
    if this.title  then content.push("#{@title}")
    if this.school then content.push(school) for school in "#{@school}"
    if this.bio    then content.push("#{@bio}")
    if this.name   then content.push(this.email("#{@name}"))
    content.join('')

fetch('http://' + apiSrc + '/' + slug + '.json')
  .then((response) -> response.json())
  .then((api) ->
    content = []
    group   = []
    group.push(new Person(them)) for them in api[slug]
    for them, index in group
      content.push(them.profile())
      console.log(content.join(''))
  )
```

But then I thought it would be even better if I could convert it to ES6. I know the use case is simple, and classes certainly aren't necessary, since I'm just using the data for templating, however, for the sake of learning, I was attempt to do this. Am I going about this the wrong way? Right now, I feel like there should be a way to return all of the "people" that I put into the `Person` class. However, the only way I could figure out how to do that was to run a for loop and then write it to the document.

```
class Person {
  constructor(data) { ({name: this.name, title: this.title, school: this.school, bio: this.bio, email: email(this.name)} = data); }
  email(username) {
    return username.replace(/\s/, '.').toLowerCase() + '@' + location.hostname.replace(/[^\.\/\@]+\.[^\.\/]+$/, '');
  }
  profile() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.title}`;
  }
}

var apiSrc = 'api.domain.com';
var slug   = 'people';
fetch(`http://${apiSrc}/${slug}.json`)
  .then(function(response) { return response.json() }) // .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function(api) {
    var content = [];
    var group = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < api[slug].length; i++) { var them = api[slug][i]; new Person(them); }
    for (var i = 0; index < group.length; i++) {
      var them = group[i];
      content.push(them.profile());
      console.log(content.join(''));
    }
  });
```

My ES6 conversion actually isn't even working right now. API returns the JSON but after that it gets messed up. Any suggestions would be really helpful as I'm trying to better myself as a coder and hope this sort of example could help others learn Classes in a real use case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*I feel like there should be a way to return all of the "people" that I put into the `Person` class*". You're doing fine, there is (and should be) no way to collect all instances of a class. You can return all of the people you put in the `group` array. That's exactly how it should work.

Comment: Since I have no experience with classes, I assumed there was some sort of return like (making this up) `Object.getClassEntries(allthePeople.constructor())`. When I return the `group` and it works, I noticed that the constructor doesn't seem to have any impact on the output. So I figured I must be doing something wrong if the constructor doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what impact you expected. Your ES6 class is quite equivalent to your CS class (disregarding the `profile` return value). What do you expect to behave differently?

Comment: Well, I wasn't convinced I did it right in the first place. If I did, then I guess I'm just seeking something that doesn't exist. So what's the point of the constructor?

Comment: What's the benefit to using classes versus just parsing the JSON straight to the output template?

Comment: Classes have methods (like `.email()`) and usually state. Often you don't need either of these, or plain functions would work just as well, but still classes are a way of organising code.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed "*My ES6 conversion actually isn't even working*" - that's probably because you forgot the `group.push()` around the call to `new Person`

Comment: You were write about the group.push, which I had earlier on, but had started to remove those since I was convinced there was a non-array approach. The main reason it wasn't working is because Safari 9 didn't like my constructor. I had to change it to this to make it work: `constructor(data) { this.name = data.name; this.title = data.title; this.school = data.school; this.bio = data.bio; this.email = this.email(data.name); }`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see before because of the scroll, but `email: email(this.name)` is not a valid destructuring (neither in CS nor ES6). And no, you don't want to do `this.email = this.email(data.name);`, that overwrites your method with a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try using the [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) parameter of `JSON.parse`.  Here is a simplified example:

```
class Person {
  // Destructure the JSON object into the parameters with defaults
  constructor ({name, title, school=[]}) {
    this.name = name
    this.title = title
    this.school = school
  }
}

var api = JSON.parse(a, function (k,v) {
  // Is this a new object being pushed into the top-level array?
  if (Array.isArray(this) && v.name) {
    return new Person(v)
  }
  return v
})

var group = api["people/administration"]
```

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought this wouldn't work because my browser had some compatibility issues and you mostly just gave me a starting place. After some time, however, I was able to implement this general idea which saves a ton of iterations from the two for loops I had going before.